# matlab simulation for value functions

Tags: matlab, reinforcement-learning

I want to simulate the following value functions.

d is a decision matrix

x=t+beta * w'

y=alpha*(c+beta * v')

v=max{x , y}

if x>y then v=x and d= 2
if x

a=phi * t+beta * w'

b=phi * c+beta * v'

w=max{a , b}

if a>b then w=a and d= 2
if a

where w' and v' on the right hand side are next period value function.

I need to track decision matrix d.

I did the following coding in matlab. But it does not seems right. What's wrong with my coding?

```
    t=1;
c=1.4;
alpha=0.5;
beta=0.8;
phi=2;
v=rand;
w=rand;
d=[0,0];
diff=100;
i=1;
%% Value Interation
while diff>0.00001 
     x=t+beta*v(i);
     y=alpha*(c+beta*w(i));
     a=phi*t+beta*v(i);
     b=phi*c+beta*w(i);
     if  x>y
         w1=x; 
         d(i,1)=2;
     else
         w1=y; 
         d(i,1)=1;
     end
     if a>b
         v1=a; 
         d(i,2)=2;
     else
         v1=b; 
         d(i,2)=1;
     end
    diff=max(abs(w(i)-w1),abs(v(i)-v1));
    i=i+1;
    w(i)=w1;
    v(i)=v1;
end
```

Comment: What error do you get? explain more about your problem.

Comment: klet me see if i understood. You want to perform the math in the text right? why don’t you use the max function, simplifying your code?

Comment: I need to track on the decision matrix. That's why I separate the function instead of using max.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want? Take special attention to the V and W variables. Your code does not seem correct based on the formula.

```
t=1;
c=1.4;
alpha=0.5;
beta=0.8;
phi=2;
v=rand;
w=rand;
d=[0,0];
diff_err=100;
i=1;

while diff_err>0.00001

    [v1,d(i,2)]=max([t+beta*w(i),alpha*(c+beta*v(i))]);
    [w1,d(i,1)]=max([phi*t+beta*w(i),phi*c+beta*v(i)]);

    diff_err=max(abs(w(i)-w1),abs(v(i)-v1));

    i=i+1;
    w(i)=w1;
    v(i)=v1;
end
```

Comment: I need to track on the decision matrix.

Comment: see if this is what you want now